# Get filerefrence full save path in Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, audio-recording, flex4.6

I am making an audio recorder web application, which records audio and saves it locally using `FileReference`:

```
private var _file:FileReference = new FileReference();
```

After recording, the user can save the file locally like:

```
_file.save( data, "filename.wav" );
```

Now, I want the full path of the saved file, but I didn't get it. How can I get the full location of a saved file?

Or can I fix the file save path in the web application? Like the user can save on the desktop only. (I know without user interaction it is not possible, but fix path to save).

Comment: You cannot get that information from a web app. Besides you can't do much with it even if you could get it.

Comment: no way if this is a web application, you should upload a recorded file  to a server app and download it to listen

Comment: @BotMaster How can i? I just want to move that file. I want to send that path to server side like .net

Comment: @JileniBouguima Yes i want to upload but from .net. So, want to send that file path to .net application.

Comment: doesn't matter a web app can't upload a file without the user approval. like I said even if you get that path your app won't be able to do anything with it anyway.

Comment: @BotMaster So how can i send recorder bytearray/audio file to .net server?

Comment: that's a different question and that is possible this time.

Comment: @BotMaster Ok so i will ask it as different question. anyways thank you.